# POSE estimation in OpenCv Java using cvFindExtrinsicsCameraParams2

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to perform POSE estimation using SIFT algorithm, using the already given method in OpenCv C++ -

cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2( const CvMat* object_points, const CvMat* image_points, const CvMat* camera_matrix, const CvMat* distortion_coeffs, CvMat* rotation_vector, CvMat* translation_vector, int use_extrinsic_guess CV_DEFAULT(0) );

I am successfully able to do it in C++ program.

I want to port this same program into an Android application.While doing this, I am not able to find the analogous method for above given function on OpenCv java.

Please help me to find the analogous method for the OpenCv function mentioned above. Also,Please suggest me any other alternative to perform POSE estimation using SIFT.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method being provided in earlier versions of OpenCv. In later versions from OpenCv 2.4.x onward, the function has been replaced with more robust implementation. Please refer to the latest OpenCv version documentation for the detailed info and new workarounds.